# Google Slides API invalid presentations id

Tags: php, google-slides-api

I'm trying to create some slides with the Slides API but I started getting this error **Invalid presentation.presentationId: The id is invalid**.

I tried to create it through the API reference without success as shown in the image:

[Reference request and error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW1OI.png)

Is there any limitation on the presentationId or some other required fields I should pass?

This is the exception I get:

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid presentation.presentationId: The id is
 invalid.",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Invalid presentation.presentationId: The id is invalid.",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "badRequest"
        }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create new Slide using `Method: presentations.create`. If my understanding is correct, how about this?

In your case, please try it using the request body with `title` and without `presentationId` as follows.

[image]

#### Note :

- At this request body, a new Slide with the filename of "Teste123" is created to the root.

#### Reference :

- [Method: presentations.create](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Dont specify a presentation ID -- just a title and the API call should work as you expect. The presentation ID will be generated by Slides for you.

Previously, Slides would ignore all presentation IDs passed in on create, but this behavior changed recently. See documentation for [presentations.create](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create)